# Java. Коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

У меня имеется список списков:

```
List<List<Object>> listOfRowsData = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

и статический метод, который возвращает List

```
DBManager.getAllRecords(tableName, s)
```

С помощью итерации заполняю спиcок:

```
for(String s : columnArray) {
        listOfRowsData.add(DBManager.getAllRecords(tableName, s));
}
```

Проблема в том, что изначально я хотел не

```
List<List<Object>> listOfRowsData
```

а

```
List<List<String>> listOfRowsData
```

Но компилятор меня поправил на `List<List<Object>> listOfRowsData`. Поэтому, собственно, вопрос - почему?

Comment: `DBManager.getAllRecords`, наверное, возвращает `List<Object>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс `String` унаследован от класса `Object`, и вы можете написать следующее:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>(); 
objList.add(new String("string"));
```

Но это правило не работает при использовании обобщенного программирования. Это значит, что `List<String>` не наследуется от `List<Object>`, и при использовании перегруженного метода `add()` для добавления списка в другой список, компилятор выдаст ошибку (собственно, что у вас и произошло). Если бы это было не так, то мы могли бы легко нарушить однородность списка:

```
List<List<Object>> objList = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); 
List<Object> intList = new ArrayList<>();
intList.add(new Integer(5));
objList.add(intList);
```

Как видим, в этом примере мы добавили список целочисленных переменных в список списков, который ожидает хранение только строковых данных.

Если вам нужен список с типом `List<List<String>>`, то можете получать результат метода `DBManager.getAllRecords(tableName, s)`, явно приводить каждый его элемент к типу `String` и добавлять в список `listOfRowsData`.

---

Дополнительные ссылки:

1. [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).
2. [Is List a subclass of List? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)